# AngularJS exporting readable code to user

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a generator that allows people to build something and at the end of it the user gets the JavaScript in a modal so they can copy and paste it for their own usage.

My problem is how to actually write and display this code.

I will only show a small portion of the code so you can see, but in the Controller I have the following

```
var gen = "&lt;script src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=" + $scope.user.api + "&sensor=false&extension=.js'&gt;&lt;/script&gt; \n \n" +
    "&lt;script&gt; \n" +
    "    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);\n" +
    "    var map;\n" +
    "    function init() {\n" +
    "        var mapOptions = {\n" +
    "            center: new google.maps.LatLng(" + $scope.user.lat + "," + $scope.user.lon + "),\n" +
    "            zoom: " + $scope.user.zoomlvl + ",\n";
if ($scope.user.zoom.val == "FALSE") {
    gen += "            zoomControl: false,\n";
} else {
    gen += "            zoomControl: true,\n" +
        "            zoomControlOptions: {\n" +
        "                style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle." + $scope.user.zoom.val + ",\n" +
        "            },\n";
}
```

In the DOM I then do `ng-bind="gen"` which outputs the above.

I'm struggling to find a common practice where I can have the code automatically nested and swapping out the variables where needed.

I was hoping someone knows of an easier and/or cleaner way because the rest of the actual code is quite messy.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are asking a way of parsing(variables where needed) and not parsing(raw code) at the same time?

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov In the above snippet, `gen` exports multiple lines of code. I want to find out and/or be suggested if there is a better way of writing it so it'll be nested and be easy for my to understand in the future as it's likely to grow

Comment: I've used lodash.template() for this in the past, and you'll find lodash good for other things as well. https://lodash.com/docs#template

Comment: I would also use $templateRequester to load the source code template so it's not hard coded into the app. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateRequest